# Java. UML. Нужна помощь в проектировании игры крестики-нолики

Tags: java, uml

Помогите, пожалуйста.
У меня такое задание:

1. Создание игры крестики нолики.
2. Вывод данных в консоль в псевдографике.
3. Пользователь начинает игру. Вводит координаты точки.
4. Предусмотреть, чтобы компьютер мог начать игру.
5. Предусмотреть увеличение поле. По умолчанию используется поле 3 на 3.
6. Предусмотреть усложнение логики игры. Выигрывает тот кто соберет 5 подряд.

Нарисовал ULM:

[image: UML для игры "Крестики-нолики".]

Знаю, что ничего хорошего, но пока не знаю, как по другому...

Самые насущные на мой взгляд вопросы:

1. Где мне хранить информацию о выигранных партиях?
2. Как сделать выбор кто за крестики кто за нолики?
3. Любые предложения и конструктивная критика от старших товарищей. Буду очень признателен.

Вообще говоря, это задание относится к объектно-ориентированному дизайну, так что буду рад если кто-то предложит интересные решения, может даже совсем не похожие...

Comment: Не вижу смысла в Move как объекте. Это состояние системы. Нарисуйте ещё граф состояний — в каких система может быть и какие переходы возможны.

Comment: Ещё у вас путаница: desk (правильно), desc, dasc. Неправильный ход незачем обрабатывать как исключение — просто разрешайте ставить отметку только туда, куда можно.

Comment: По поводу UML можно с уверенностью сказать одно: когда вы начнёте разработку, поменяется хотя бы что-нибудь, но скорее процентов 50. Поэтому делайте прототип, проводите разведку боем. Тогда вы поймёте, какая структура должна быть. И будьте морально готовы выкинуть код прототипа и начать заново.

Comment: `Где мне хранить информацию о выигранных партиях` – в задаче не сказано, что это нужно хранить между запусками приложения. Просто так хранить можно в переменной. Не усложняйте задачу )

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказки!

Comment: Советую прочитать книгу «Clean Code» (Martin). Лучше - в оригинале, хотя можно и в переводе. Боб Мартин «Чистый код». Она поможет перейти со ступени "могу написать рабочий код" на "пишу читаемый код".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ненавижу UML как явление, как сущность, как продукт. В реальной жизни не видел ни одного разработчика, который бы спроектировал что-то путное на UML. UML классный инструмент, если надо зад**чить бедного студента или завалить зарвавшегося junior'а на интервью. Здесь походу, как раз тот самый случай когда препод решил завалить студента :)

В реальной жизни работает *agile* подход: когда в голове выстраивается некая конструкция, на основе этой конструкции пишется некий работающий макет, далее конструкция модифицируется, потом опять создается макет, опять модифицируется и т.д. Когда конструкция становится более-менее вменяемой пишется уже UML дизайн и рапортуется мудрому руководству, которое с умным видом начинает править UML примитивы :)

В итоге все счастливы и все смеются: разработчик имеет рабочий прототип, руководство UML схему, которая уже воплощена в жизнь.

Предположу, что здесь надо идти по тому же пути: начать реализацию "крестиков-ноликов" на уровне общего прототипа с заглушками вместо реальных шагов и отрисовки. Потом переложить полученные в результате штурмовки классы на UML диаграммы.

**Update**

> А подскажите как тогда накидать сложную структуру чтобы было наглядно и удобно? Именно для себя не для отчетов?

Agile вам в помощь: Любая нормальная Java IDE позволяет легко писать классы. Пишите сразу классы (то есть сущности), без методов, но с полями. Когда будут нарисованы классы, более-менее будет ясно что делать с методами. Потом выяснится, что либо классов много, либо их не хватает - итерируете. Через пару-тройку итераций все станет ясно. Если итераций будет больше 3-4, значит вы еще не поняли задачу - посидите, попейте кофе, покурите, помедитируйте и опять по новой. Когда прояснится с методами, можно начать абстрагировать - вводить интерфейсы, абстрактные классы, всякие паттерны и проч.

Comment: Удивил ваш ответ и реакция на него. Вы говорите - UML не нужен разработчику. А как писать если бы приложение было-бы не крестики нолики, а имело 50 классов? Как-то же надо себе представить хотя-бы в целом как оно будет.

Comment: UML нужен как средство документирования, но не как дизайна, говорю вам как человек с опытом программирования еще со времен, когда 4k оперативки были роскошью :)

Comment: А подскажите как тогда накидать сложную структуру чтобы было наглядно и удобно?  Именно для себя не для отчетов? Чтобы можно было прикинуть как оно все будет? Что использовать?

Comment: UML - это прекрасное средство дизайна, говорю вам как человек, который уже 5 лет не держал в руках авторучку или карандаш

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: >>>Update... <<< Большое спасибо за совет, попробую так.

Answer (score 4):

У ваших классов размытые ответственности.

Возьмем класс Desc. Что он вообще делает? Создает и хранит матрицу строк?..

Есть такое правило - [Tell-Don’t-Ask](https://habrahabr.ru/post/192706/). Не надо спрашивать у доски ее состояние чтобы его обработать - надо приказать доске эту обработку произвести!

Конечно же, однажды вам все равно придется вытащить из доски матрицу, для обработки тем же ботом. Но надо при этом ее максимально подготовить! К примеру, зачем вообще боту знать крестиками или ноликами он играет? Ему важны не абсолютные цвета (крестик-нолик), а относительные (свой-чужой). Вот это преобразование и должна делать доска.

---

У класса Position слишком много ответственностей. Он и хранит ход игрока - и он же его считывает! Это неправильно. Считывание должно остаться внутри User/UserInput (кстати, зачем они вообще разделены?) - а у Position (который правильнее было бы назвать Move) должна остаться только 1 ответственность.

Кстати, зачем в Position хранится символ? Игрок что, может выбирать крестиками или ноликами он делает очередной ход? :)

---

Теперь про класс Game. У него опять две ответственности - он и определяет победителя (ради чего доска ему передает свое внутреннее состояние!), и следит за игрой. Не надо так. Пусть выигрышную позицию определяет доска, являясь тем самым единственной точкой расширения.

Почему игра различает игрока-человека и игрока-бота? Какая игре разница кто в нее играет? Вам что, на игру двух ботов смотреть не интересно? И зачем вообще вы делали им общий интерфейс, если игра все равно обращается к ним отдельно? Игра должна различать игрока, играющего крестиками - и игрока, играющего ноликами. А кто из них человек - никому не интересные подробности!

---

И последнее. У вас ни пользователь, ни бот не имеют доступа к текущей позиции. Это так и задумано? :)

Comment: 1) >>К примеру, зачем вообще боту знать крестиками или ноликами он играет? Ему важны не абсолютные цвета (крестик-нолик), а относительные (свой-чужой)<< а как же мне распознать свой чужой я это и собирался делать через крестик-нолик, а как еще? 2).>> У класса Position слишком много ответственностей. Он и хранит ход игрока - и он же его считывает! Это неправильно. Считывание должно остаться внутри User/UserInput (кстати, зачем они вообще разделены?)<< я не понял так они должны буть разделены или нет? Ну я слышал такое правило не помню название что где данные создаются там и обрабатываются. не?

Comment: >>Почему игра различает игрока-человека и игрока-бота? Какая игре разница кто в нее играет? Вам что, на игру двух ботов смотреть не интересно? И зачем вообще вы делали им общий интерфейс, если игра все равно обращается к ним отдельно?<< я сделал им общий интерфейс что-бы использовать полиморфизм в цикле крутящем игру, и у обоих вызывать метод move() а там версия с ботом чего-то генерит а для пользователя инпут срабатыват. Не вы считаете не удачная идея?

Comment: Классы должны быть маленькими и их ответственность должна быть весьма ограниченной. Принцип "кто данные создает - тот и обрабатывает" - очень сомнительный. Получается, что в Word класс, который сохраняет/считывает данные должен их же отображать и проверять на орфографию?

Comment: >>И последнее. У вас ни пользователь, ни бот не имеют доступа к текущей позиции. Это так и задумано? :) << через гетер доски...  не очень?

Comment: @Stepan нет, не должен. Но определенно класс, отвечающий за орфографию, также не должен сохранять и загружать.

Comment: @Павел 1) ну хорошо. Крестик - это свой или чужой?

Comment: @Павел 2) Position - это типичный DTO. К DTO такое правило неприменимо.

Comment: @Павел 3) какая разница вызывать move() напрямую или через интерфейс - если у вас переменные user и bot?

Comment: @Павел 4) так как вы вызовите геттер у доски - если ссылки на доску у вас нет?

Comment: 2) Position - это типичный DTO. К DTO такое правило неприменимо. Извините а как расшифровывается DTO ? 1) ну хорошо. Крестик - это свой или чужой? Так и я вот не пойму как это решить, Можно разрешить всем ставить и крестики и нолики но как понять кто за кого... не пойму как это сделать... 4) так как вы вызовите геттер у доски - если ссылки на доску у вас нет? А ну это косяк я так и не решил где именно она будет толи статическую ее сделать, то ли гетером доступаться, то ли из класса Game то ли из Desc, но Desc вы говорите вроде вообще не нужен. Чем больше я думаю тем меньше понимаю...

Comment: @Павел прочитайте что я написал еще раз.

Comment: Ух читаю я читаю((((... Вот тут у меня главный косяк но как его поправить... >>>Кстати, зачем в Position хранится символ? Игрок что, может выбирать крестиками или ноликами он делает очередной ход? :)<<< как то мне надо сделать чтобы в начале игры выбирался крестик или нолик и от пользователей поступали только позиции куда его поставить но как

Comment: @Павел эту информацию должна хранить игра, а не игроки или позиция

Comment: Да это звучит очень логично, Но как именно если позиция поступила от того-то то тогда ставим крестик и тд?

Comment: @Павел что "как именно"?